# AngularJs ng-click event only triggered with literal arguments

Tags: events, click, angularjs

When I call within a ng-repeat group

`<span ng-click="remove({{user.id}})">Delete</span>`

the **remove** function is **not** called

but when I replace the expression by a literal argument it gets called (works properly):

`<span ng-click="remove(123)">Delete</span>`

The '{{user.id}}' expression is evaluated properly and has only integer values.

Anybody an idea what is going on? Same happens with anchor tags (with href="").

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`ng-click="remove(user.id)"` should work, ng-click evaluate it content so you don't need interpolation

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. What irritated me is that no exception was thrown and the html code looked absolutely ok, because the expression had been evaluated properly.

Comment: To be more specific, ngClick will run whatever string is inside it's quotes through $eval(). More information can be found here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$eval

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't use curly braces in the ng-click expressions. Try this instead:

```
<span ng-click="remove(user.id)">Delete</span>
```

And be sure to check the AngularJS expressions documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression