# Angular ng-click and click handler in directive

Tags: angularjs, click

I have a ng-click defined as an attribute for an anchor, but I also have a directive (ink-button) attached to it.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button button--pink" 
ng-click="vm.onSubmit()" ink-button>
```

The ng-click is for handling a specific function, while the directive is used pure for a generic animation for all the buttons. Inside my directive (inkButton) I have a click handler. And when I click the button, only the eventhandler in the directive is responding, and the ng-click is being ignored.
How to fix this?

Comment: Please provide the code of your directive .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512572/ng-click-not-firing-in-angularjs-while-onclick-does

Comment: Does the directive swallow the click event with something like `$event.stopPropagation()`?