# Angular ng-click not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have tried many different things to try to get this to work.
I have read:

[ng-click not firing in AngularJS while onclick does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512572/ng-click-not-firing-in-angularjs-while-onclick-does)

[AngularJS : ng-click not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422584/angularjs-ng-click-not-working)

and a lot more

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="testApp">
  <div id="bla">
    <button ng-click="obey('bla')">Close</button>
    <h4>Bla bla bla</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);
testApp.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.obey = function test(id) {
    $("#" + id).fadeOut("slow", function() {
      this.remove()
    });
  };
});
```

For some reason the div does not fade out at all.

Comment: Just a hint, you should avoid DOM manipulations while using AngularJS please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background. jQuery is not required/recommend when using AngularJS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You specified your app name in `controller`. check this.

```js
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);
testApp.controller('testController', function($scope) {
  $scope.obey = function test(id) {
    $scope.hide= !$scope.hide;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
  <div id="bla">
    <button ng-click="obey('bla')">Close</button>
    <h4 ng-hide="hide">Bla bla bla</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I do that on jsfiddle it does not want to work though it works on this page. https://jsfiddle.net/DrevanTonder/sguy6agL/

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me it's something wrong with name of your controller. Try this:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
  <div id="bla">
    <button ng-click="obey('bla')">Close</button>
    <h4>Bla bla bla</h4>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `ng-show` or `ng-hide` in this case

```
<div ng-controller="testApp">
  <div id="bla">
    <button ng-click="obey()">Close</button>
    <h4  ng-show="viewDiv">Bla bla bla</h4>
  </div>
</div>

var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);
testApp.controller('testController', function($scope) {
 $scope.viewDiv = true;
  $scope.obey = function test(id) {
   $scope.viewDiv = !$scope.viewDiv;
  };
});
```

for angular animation - refer [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_animation)

Answer (score 0):

specified proper "ng-app" and "ng-controller" name

HTML ie.

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
      <div id="bla">
        <button ng-click="obey('bla')">Close</button>
        <h4>Bla bla bla</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
<body>
```